Await is not waiting in Async Function with for Loop Angular 12
I have the following async function, which itself is sitting inside a loop. This async function goes through a loop to find the name of the image and then request the URL using await on the promised base function getDownloadURL(), which is an angular/fire/storage function for google cloud storage. Everything works, but the loop is not stopping to await the return of the URL, so it can be added to the object and saved into a database.
for (let x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
 (async () => {
  let o = {};
  for (let y = 0; y < headerRow.length; y++) {
    this.titledata = headerRow[y].trim();
    this.csvdata = data[x][y].trim();
    if(this.titledata = "IMAGE_NAME') {
      this.o['imageName'] = this.csvdata;

      const path = `items/${this.o['imageName']}`
      const storageRef = ref(this.storage, path);
      this.o[`imageURL'] = await getDownloadURL(storageRef)
    };
   };
  };
};


Can you please try the below code:
async processImages(data: any[], headerRow: string[]) {
      const promises = data.map(async (row) => {
        let o: any = {};
        for (let y = 0; y < headerRow.length; y++) {
          this.titledata = headerRow[y].trim();
          this.csvdata = row[y].trim();
          if (this.titledata === "IMAGE_NAME") {
            o['imageName'] = this.csvdata;
    
            const path = `items/${o['imageName']}`;
            const storageRef = ref(this.storage, path);
            o['imageURL'] = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
          }
        }
        // Save the object to the database here
        await this.saveToDatabase(o);
      });
    
      await Promise.all(promises);
    }
    
    async saveToDatabase(o: any) {
      // Your logic to save the object to the database
    }


The "await getDownloadURL(storageRef)" is still not waiting to be resolved before calling the database
